# Wondering about HexEditor program's loading performance

Tags: performance, file, hex, loading, large-files

25GB file into my (self made)hex Viewer make's loading endlessly.

but 25GB file into HxD(free Software), it doesn't takes just one second!

how can it be possible!?

i wondering about principle of HxD.

help me please..?

Comment: It loaded whole file in a second!!!??????

Comment: I doubt HxD is loading the file completely. It only loads where you're looking at, if you scroll, it loads the next parts, discarding the earlier loaded bytes.

Comment: So this is part of software.When you read the file so it reads first few lines which is visible to you and later it is loading the other section of program.But maximum program loaded will depend upon your RAM.

Comment: how can i search information about "load only looking at?". can i get code snippet... or references ? it has terminology?

Answer (score 0):

One thing is how big files your editor can edit theoretically. But another thing is, is it fast enough to realistically edit that file.

Most editors use the easy way and simply load the whole file in memory. This means that you can not edit files larger than the largest free memory block. This gets even worse if the editor converts ASCII file into Unicode, which doubles the size. With editors like this, just opening the file may take several minutes. But even if you can load the file, any editing operations may be so slow that you really can not do anything.

You will get better info on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors#Extra_features).